# sending json data to server returns 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post, http-post

I want to send my string value to server as json data, but i get 400 bad request.
here is the code how i am sending data.

```
dataString = '{"comment":"'  +dataString+ '"}';
        dataString = '[' + dataString + ']';

         $.parseJSON(dataString);
         console.debug("After parsing : "+dataString);

        $(form_element).clearForm();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : loc,
            cache : false,
            data : dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",

            success : function(data) {
                console.debug("After success");
            }
```

When i debug the code, the @RequestParameter "comment" have null value. 
Kindly help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the initial value of dataString when you could console.debug("After parsing...");

Comment: a simple string e.g ("hi david")

Comment: Not but my question is, do you actually set it?  It's not just carrying through the code as null?

Comment: i set its value by reading a text field value and store it in the string, its the comments field as we can see in any website where users can comments on a feed. User's comment is stored in dataSting (variable) from where i am sending it to server for storing in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shoud pass json object NOT json array.

```
var dataString = '{"comment":"test"}';
    //dataString = '[' + dataString + ']';  //delete this, NOT array
var obj = $.parseJSON(dataString);
console.log(obj);

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    cache : false,
    data : obj,
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",

    success : function(data) {
        console.debug("After success");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function returns an object.

You should do

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(dataString);

$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : loc,
        cache : false,
        data : obj,
```

That's supposing you really need to build your string as you do. It's generally simpler to just build your object instead of making a json string, parsing it then asking jQuery to serialize it again.

Comment: What's initially in dataString and what's received/expected by the server ? Does it want an array ?

Comment: its a simple string value but server receive null value